# File with information about filesystem block size (in Linux)

Tags: filesystems, linux

I wonder if filesystem block size is presented in any of file in /proc or /sys directory.

Comment: I don't think so... are you looking for [statvfs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/statvfs.2.html)?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use [`stat --file-system`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stat.1.html#contenttoc2) to get information about a filesystem:

```
% stat --file-system /
  File: "/"
    ID: 5901e0357ca07cae Namelen: 255     Type: ext2/ext3
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 2580302    Free: 412729     Available: 386515
Inodes: Total: 655360     Free: 314397
```

If you just want the block size:

```
% stat --file-system --format='%S' /
4096
```